# Owin IdentityUser to UserProfile Class

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity

I have a UserProfile class with Guid Id. The Owin IdentityUser has an Int Id. I am trying to link the IdentityUser to the UserProfileClass. I know how to convert an Int to Guid, but this allows only 4 byte number of user and not 16 bytes as I wish. How to overcome this?

Comment: add `int UserId { get; set; }` to UserProfile for the IdentityUser FK

Comment: still the same problem, it will allow only 2 power 32 UserProfile which is less than the Guid allows.

Comment: Do not perform conversions. Add an FK with the same type as the PK.